# How can I have dynamic function to pass in debounce function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I want implement different api search in one React component and I using custom hook.

```
 const { request:requestOne, data, loading} = useApi(searchOneApiConfig);
 const { request:requestTwo, data, loading} = useApi(searchTwoApiConfig);
 const { request:requestThree, data, loading} = useApi(searchThreeApiConfig);
```

now I have to use a useCallback(debounce... for each one like:

```
const SearchLazyQueryOne = useCallback(debounce(requestOne, DEBOUNCED_TIME, LazyQueryConfig), []);
const SearchLazyQueryTwo = useCallback(debounce(requestTwo, DEBOUNCED_TIME, LazyQueryConfig), []); 
const SearchLazyQueryThree = useCallback(debounce(requestThree DEBOUNCED_TIME, LazyQueryConfig), []);
```

My question is how can I have single "searchLazyQuery" and pass dynamic request function?

(I'm using Lodash's [`debounce`](https://lodash.dev/docs/4.17.15#debounce).)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it sounds like you want to use:

```
searchLazyQuery(requestTwo, /*...args*/)
```

...while debouncing the calls to `requestTwo`. That will require keeping track of the debounced functions and using the matching one (or creating one as needed).

You can store the debounced versions of the function in a `Map`. Here's a sketch of a hook that does that:

```
const useDynamicDebounce = (debouncedTime, config) => {
    // Using a ref to provide a stability guarantee on the function we return
    const ref = useRef(null);
    if (!ref.current) {
        // A map to keep track of debounced functions
        const debouncedMap = new Map();
        // The function we return
        ref.current = (fn, ...args) => {
            // Get the debounced version of this function
            let debounced = debouncedMap.get(fn);
            if (!debounced) {
                // Don't have one yet, create it
                debounced = debounce(fn, debouncedTime, config);
                debouncedMap.set(fn, debounced);
            }
            // Do the call
            return debounced(...args);
        };
    }
    return ref.current;
};
```

Using it in your component:

```
const searchLazyQuery = useDynamicDebounce(DEBOUNCED_TIME, LazyQueryConfig);
```

Then use `searchLazyQuery(requestTwo, "args", "for", "requestTwo")` (for example).